# Python: How to extract DNA sequence based on a text file with binary content?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

For example I have a fasta file with the following
sequences:

```
>human1
AGGGCGSTGC
>human2
GCTTGCGCTAG
>human3
TTCGCTAG
```

How to use python to read a text file with the following content to extract the
sequences? 1 represents true and 0 represents false. Only sequence with value 1
will be extracted.

Example text file:

```
0
1
1
```

Expected output:

```
>human2
GCTTGCGCTAG
>human3
TTCGCTAG
```

Comment: your question is to general. did you write some code?

Comment: Trying to gain some clarity. So you have a file of DNA sequences, and a _separate_ text file with a 0 or a 1 on each line? And then you want to parse the text file to determine which sequences are valid? Is the text file actually binary format or are the 0 and 1s that you refer to plainly written in ascii(or some other encoding) text?

Comment: The text file is plainly 0 and 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for this is better to use biopython

```
from Bio import SeqIO

mask = ["1"==_.strip() for _ in open("mask.txt")]
seqs = [seq for seq in SeqIO.parse(open("input.fasta"), "fasta")]
seqs_filter = [seq for flag, seq in zip(mask, seqs) if flag]
for seq in seqs_filter:
  print seq.format("fasta")
```

you get:

```
>human2
GCTTGCGCTAG
>human3
TTCGCTAG
```

**explanation**

*parse fasta:* the format fasta may to have several lines of sequences (check [fasta format](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fasta/info)), is better to use a specialized library to read (parser) and write the output

*mask:* I read de mask file and cast to boolean `[False, True, True]`

*filter*: use zip function for each sequence match with his mask, and following i use list Comprehensions to filter

Answer (score 3):

I think this may help you and I really think you should take some time learn Python. Python is a good language for bioinformatics.

```
display = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        display.append(int(line.strip()))

output_DNA = []
with open('XX.fasta') as f:
    index = -1
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0] == '>':
            index = index + 1

        if display[index]:
            output_DNA.append(line)

print output_DNA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an list to act like a mask for when you read your fasta file:

```
with open('mask.txt') as mf:
    mask = [ s.strip() == '1' for s in mf.readlines() ]
```

Then:

```
with open('seq.fasta') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if mask[i]:
            *something* line
```

or:

```
from itertools import izip

for b, line in izip(open(mask_file), open(seq_file)):
    if b.strip() == '1':
          *something* line
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the fasta file format specifically but hopefully this helps. You can open your file in python the following way and extract the valid line entries in a list.

```
valid = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines() # get all the lines
    all_lines = [x.strip() for x in all_lines] # strip away newline chars
    for i in range(len(all_lines)):
        if all_lines[i] == '1': # if it matches our condition
            valid.append(i) # add the index to our list

    print valid # or get only the fasta file contents on these lines
```

I ran it with the following text file test.txt:

```
0
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

And got output when printing `valid`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

I think this will help you move along, but please let me know in the comments if you need an expanded answer.